# Understaning tf2 demo launch file

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have one more question regarding the same on this page [Writing a tf2 broadcaster (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29)(section 3 Running the broadcaster).

Why we need to initiate two different node named  turtle1_tf2_broadcaster & turtle2_tf2_broadcaster.
Can anyone explain whole code inside **start_demo.launch** which is here:

```
 <launch>
      <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
      <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>

    <node name="turtle1_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf2" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle1" />
    </node>
    <node name="turtle2_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf2" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle2" /> 
    </node>

  </launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294614/understaning-tf2-demo-launch-file/) by [viveksudani](https://answers.ros.org/users/30256/viveksudani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS launch files are used to start multiple nodes with one command. In the above example one starts the same node multiple times but using different parameters. So basically following will happens:

1. one starts turtle sim node with a name **sim**
2. teleoperation node for turtlesim node is started
3. node with a name **turtle1_tf2_broadcaster** is started and listens on a topic */turtle1/pose*
4. node with a name **turtle2_tf2_broadcaster** is started and listens on a topic */turtle2/pose*

So basically the two broadcasters will broadcast different stuff depending on subscribed topic.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viveksudani](https://answers.ros.org/users/30256/viveksudani/) on 2018-06-24**:
@destogl, Thanks for reply. your explanation is well understood.
But why we need two broadcasters. since we are running only one turtlesim node. I mean can't we run only one broadcaster instead of two?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-24**:
If you read carefully the explanation on the end of the page you will see that second broadcaster is needed in the next tutorial. And here is just added for teaching purposes. See: *Checking the results* part

**Comment by [viveksudani](https://answers.ros.org/users/30256/viveksudani/) on 2018-06-24**:
Yay!  I missed that lines. By the way thank you so much. Now i m clear that second broadcaster has no role to play yet.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-06-24**:
You are welcome! If you are happy with answer please mark it as answered.